# How to get a deafult string value for blanks in a Power BI Desktop measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

---

I have two tables ( Sales[OrderNumer,Price,ItemId,...] and Item[Id, Name, Type] ) and I have a measure that returns a string like that:

```
 ItemsType1 = CALCULATE(
     CONCATENATEX('Sales', RELATED('Item'[Name]), ","), 'Item'[Type] = "type1"
```

I have a table visual in Power BI Desktop at Order level with the measure ItemsType1 [OrderNumer, ItemsType1]. I want to change BLANK values of ItemType1 column by a default value like "n/a" and I rewrote the measure as:

```
 ItemsType1 = VAR x = CALCULATE(
     CONCATENATEX('Sales', RELATED('Item'[Name]), ","), 'Item'[Type] = "type1") 
 RETURN IF( ISBLANK(x), "n/a", x )
```

The measure returns the expected value, but in this way, for my 600000 rows in `Sales` table, the memory grows abruptly and the visual collapses. I have 16GB of memory. I think the problem is with the IF statement but I do not know why.  I would like to understand why this difference in performance and what is the best way to do this.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the reason it's blowing up is that because of the way you have it written, it will return `"n/a"` for **ALL** possible things in the table, not just the `type1` ones you're filtering on.

The solution is to move the `IF` inside the concatenation. Try something like this:

```
ItemsType1 =
CALCULATE (
    CONCATENATEX ( 'Sales',
        IF(ISBLANK( RELATED ( 'Item'[Name] ) )
            "n/a",
            RELATED ( 'Item'[Name] )
        ),
    "," ),
    'Item'[Type] = "type1"
)
```

---

The above isn't working quite how I expected. Try changing your `RETURN` line to this instead:

```
RETURN
    IF(
        COUNTROWS( RELATEDTABLE( 'Item' ) ) = 0,
        BLANK(),
        IF( ISBLANK( x ), "n/a", x )
    )
```

This checks for any empty related table before doing any heavier computing.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but the rows that doesn't have a related Item of `type1` remain blank. It's like the `concatenatex` expression is only evaluated for those rows than have a related `type1` item and as result the measure is blank for the rest. I also tried with other conditions in the `IF` statement.

Comment: You are correct. It won't return anything outside of `type1`. I thought this was what you were after. Can you specify exactly which levels you want to show `n/a` and which levels to leave blank? A screenshot of your visual would help.

Comment: Sure, I updated the question with a link to an example image. I need a `n/a` for the order 1003 which has no related item of `type1`. My sales table has around 600000 rows.

Comment: Hi, I try your solution but the memory performance is the same. I think that `COUNTROWS( RELATEDTABLE( 'Item' ) ) = 0` is always `false` for my case.

Comment: Hmmm. What if you wrap that in a `CALCULATE`? `CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE('Item')), 'Item'[Type] = "type1") = 0`

Answer (score 0):

With the IF statement in your measure you are asking the visual to return one row for each order number. How many order numbers are in your dataset? A possible reason could be that the number of rows in the visual is too large.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34400689)